# Этимология слова "дача"

Tags: этимология

Русское слово "дача" имеет по крайней мере два значения: (1) акт предоставления; (2) коттедж, дом в пригороде.

Является ли второе значение связанным  этимологически с тем же корнем "давать" первого значения?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопросы про русский язык для неносителей задаются на http://russian.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Что плохого-то, что он не по-русски спросил? Вопрос ведь хороший!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой вопрос должен быть понятен всем. Если форум русскоязычный, то вопросы и ответы должны быть только на русском. Если билингвальным, как тот, на который я дал ссылку выше, то допустимы два языка. Иначе это будет затруднять поиск и засорять главную страницу. Тут есть пользователи, которым удобнее было бы писать на армянском, украинском или татарском может и им так делать? Найти русскую раскладку онлайн, нет особых проблем и пользователь хотя бы покажет степень владения русским языком, что бы было понятно на каком уровне следует отвечать.

Comment: @Марк Из, gde est' takaya raskladka?

Comment: @Mikhail Katz А где гугл находится, вам тоже показать?   Ну вот здесь например. http://loderi.com/ru

Comment: Понятно, Марк, убедили.)

Answer (score 4):

Вообще, первые дачи появились в XVIII в. при Петре I и давались царём за заслуги перед государством, так что, да, "дача" и "дать" этимологически связаны. Современное значение, по этимологическому словарю Н. М. Шанского - Т. М. Бобровой, появилось с первой трети XIX в., но образовано от более раннего значения.

Comment: Spasibo. U vas est' istochnik dlia etoi informatsii?

Comment: @MikhailKatz изменил и дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Я дополню Марка Иза. "Дача" родственно "давать", но на очень древнем уровне. Непосредственно "дача" - "загородный дом" - произошло от слова "дар", напрямую с "дача" (от "дать") не связано. Характерно, что Кузнецов выделяет и третье значение слова "дача" - незастроенный участок земли, обычно под лесом. Вот это-то третье значение напрямую связано с разбираемым. Первые загородные дачи для летнего отдыха строились именно на таких пригородных участках земли, передаваемых знатным людям в качестве дара. 
Но, с другой стороны, слово "дар" само по себе родственно слову "дать". Так что совсем отрицать родство всех значений слово "дача" было бы тоже неправильно.
Подробности - см. Википедию и словари.

Comment: Thanks. Do you agree that the meaning of dacha as gift from the king originates from the 19th century as Iz noted? Could you provide some sources?

Comment: @MikhailKatz Yes, I do. But I'm just an amateur, Wiki is my best source. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0 Марк Из knows more, should be.

Answer (score 1):

Из Википедии [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Дача](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0)

Считается, что первые дачи появились в России ещё в начале XVIII века, в эпоху Петра I. Изначально это были, скорее, не дачи, а усадьбы под Петербургом, которые царь даровал своим приближённым за заслуги перед государством. Хотя как раз тогда вошло в обиход слово **«дача» — производное от глагола «давать»**.

Comment: Примечательно, что заимствование термина Дача в английский язык (dacha) также прослеживается с 1800 годов и ранее. (По данным гугла https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1C1GCEU_ruRU820RU820&ei=FU5fXpjdLJOEk74Pz52A2AE&q=dacha+etymology&oq=dacha+etymology&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0.10985.20268..20759...0.1..0.99.676.7......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0i7i30j0i13j0i7i10i30j0i8i7i30j0i8i13i30j0i7i30i19.BDhzybhxQes&ved=0ahUKEwjYu-zpm4DoAhUTwsQBHc8OABsQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)